# fill in NA based on the last non-NA value for each group in R

Tags: r, dplyr, na

My question is I have a dataframe `m` as below

```
y1 =c( rep("A",5),rep("B",5))
y2 = rep(c(1:5),2)
y3 = y2
y3[c(2,7,9)]=NA
m = data.frame(y1,y2,y3)

   y1 y2   y3
1   A  1    1
2   A  2 <NA>
3   A  3    3
4   A  4    4
5   A  5    5
6   B  1    1
7   B  2 <NA>
8   B  3    3
9   B  4 <NA>
10  B  5    5
```

I want to fill in the NA based on the closest non-NA value "in front of" this NA. My output should look like this:

```
   y1 y2   y3 y4
1   A  1    1  1
2   A  2 <NA>  1
3   A  3    3  3
4   A  4    4  4
5   A  5    5  5
6   B  1    1  1
7   B  2 <NA>  1
8   B  3    3  3
9   B  4 <NA>  3
10  B  5    5  5
```

Any idea about how to use `dplyr` to achieve this goal?

Comment: `locf` won't handle the heading missing values, the `nomb` won't handle trailling missing values... if you have a group all with missing values, what neither will work...

Comment: good point, but we don't yet know whether those come up in the OP's context or not.  Since they say "in front of" it sounds like they don't, but only the OP can say for sure.  The solution below (and linked) does work for the OP's example.  A slightly clunky solution would use `zoo::na.locf` twice, with and without `fromLast`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This may have been answered before, but I don't know if it's been answered in a `dplyr` context.  `zoo::na.locf()` is your friend:

```
m %>% group_by(y1) %>% mutate(y4=zoo::na.locf(y3))
```

Comment: ooops, took about the same length of time to answer as to search for "[r] na.locf dplyr" on SO ...

Comment: thanks!! I never used `zoo` package before...that's why I never thought about that..

Comment: not suggesting that you should have searched (it only works if you know what to search for), but that I should have searched & marked as duplicate before I answered.