# group_by() into fill() not working as expected

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I'm trying to do a Last Observation Carried Forward operation on some poorly formatted data using `dplyr` and `tidyr`.  It isn't working as I'd expect.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
                 email=c('bob@email.com', NA, 'joe@email.com', NA, NA, NA))
df2 <- df %>% group_by(id) %>% fill(email)
```

This results in:

```
Source: local data frame [6 x 2]
Groups: id [3]

     id         email
  (dbl)        (fctr)
1     1 bob@email.com
2     1 bob@email.com
3     2 joe@email.com
4     2 joe@email.com
5     3 joe@email.com
6     3 joe@email.com
```

I expect it to be:

```
Source: local data frame [6 x 2]
Groups: id [3]

     id         email
  (dbl)        (fctr)
1     1 bob@email.com
2     1 bob@email.com
3     2 joe@email.com
4     2 joe@email.com
5     3 NA
6     3 NA
```

The reason I expect it to be the latter is because of `group_by`'s documentation saying, "The `group_by` function takes an existing tbl and converts it into a grouped tbl where operations are performed "by group"."  The group in this case is determined by the `id` variable, and the following operation is `fill(email)`.  However, it's pretty clearly NOT doing that.

---

And before anybody asks, it makes no difference if the fields are both `character` instead of `numeric` or `factor`.

---

**UPDATE**
@aosmith pointed out [this open issue](https://github.com/hadley/tidyr/issues/129) on Github. I'm going to say that there won't be a proper solution to this problem until that issue is resolved.  Everything else would just be a workaround.  So, if somebody makes a successful PR addressing that issue and posts it here, I'd be happy to mark it as the solution.

Comment: Looks like there is an [open issue](https://github.com/hadley/tidyr/issues/129) about this on the github repository

Comment: If your question is how to do this in dplyr without `fill` (which doesn't currently appear to respect grouping), there are duplicates [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207162/fill-in-na-based-on-the-last-non-na-value-for-each-group-in-r) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340150/using-dplyr-window-functions-to-make-trailing-values)

Comment: Thanks for the Github issue link!  I did end up making a workaround using `ddply()` with `fill()`, but I guess the fact that the issue exists means that a proper solution will only come as a resolution to that issue.

Comment: As a work-around that doesn't require `zoo`, do see [Wojciech's answer over here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27461663/903061).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like this has been fixed in the development version of *tidyr*.  You now get the expected result per id using `fill` from tidyr_0.3.1.9000.

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% fill(email)

Source: local data frame [6 x 2]
Groups: id [3]

     id         email
  (dbl)        (fctr)
1     1 bob@email.com
2     1 bob@email.com
3     2 joe@email.com
4     2 joe@email.com
5     3            NA
6     3            NA
```

Comment: Indeed, this is fixed in the new 0.4.0 version available in CRAN.

Answer (score 8):

Luckily you can still use `zoo::na.locf` for this:

```
df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(email = zoo::na.locf(email, na.rm = FALSE))  
# Source: local data frame [6 x 2]
# Groups: id [3]
# 
#      id         email
#   (dbl)        (fctr)
# 1     1 bob@email.com
# 2     1 bob@email.com
# 3     2 joe@email.com
# 4     2 joe@email.com
# 5     3            NA
# 6     3            NA
```

Comment: Good idea, but I and my coworkers consider it poor practice to use a package whose primary purpose is time series analysis for data normalization.  If this were a time series problem it would be fair game, but not here.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `do` from `dplyr`:

```
df3 <- df %>% group_by(id) %>% do(fill(.,email))
```

Comment: This is probably the best workaround listed. However, I'm still going to stand by my note above about it not being properly answered until there's a fix to the package. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Two questions, does it has be duplicated and do you have to use `dplyr` and `tidyr`?

Maybe this could be a solution?

```
(
bar <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
                 email=c('bob@email.com', NA, 'joe@email.com', NA, NA, NA))
)                 
#> id         email
#>  1 bob@email.com
#>  1          <NA>
#>  2 joe@email.com
#>  2          <NA>
#>  3          <NA>
#>  3          <NA>

(                 
foo <- bar[!duplicated(bar$id),]
)
#> id         email
#>  1 bob@email.com
#>  2 joe@email.com
#>  3          <NA>
```

Comment: There's more data to the right in the actual data that I'm working on, I just wanted to illustrate the problem in the most terse manner possilbe.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of ugly, but it is another option that uses `dplyr` and works with your sample data

```
df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(email = email[ !is.na(email) ][1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this issue quite a few times, I do worry about using this..

`df2 <- df %>% group_by(id) %>% fill(email)`

on large data sets as I have had mixed results and found the following work around. The split function used with map_df ensures you apply whatever you are doing to the a specific df for each id and map_df then re binds all the individual df like magic. It has also proved handy in lots of other circumstances. Somewhat obsolete now this issue has been fixed but still a useful alternative that avoids group_by().

`df %>% split(.$id) %>% map_df(function(x){ x %>% fill(email)})`