# Fill gaps using a group mean in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data set which has gaps in one of the columns (temp). I am trying to fill the gaps using the "temp" data from a "sensor" or mean of "sensors" within the same "treatment", and of course same date stamp. I am trying to do this using tidyverse/lubridate.

```
date    treatment   sensor  temp
1/01/2019   1   A   30
2/01/2019   1   A   29.1
3/01/2019   1   A   21.2
4/01/2019   1   A   NA
1/01/2019   1   B   20.5
2/01/2019   1   B   19.8
3/01/2019   1   B   35.1
4/01/2019   1   B   23.5
1/01/2019   2   C   31.2
2/01/2019   2   C   32.1
3/01/2019   2   C   28.1
4/01/2019   2   C   31.2
1/01/2019   2   D   NA
2/01/2019   2   D   26.5
3/01/2019   2   D   27.9
4/01/2019   2   D   28
```

This is what I am expecting:

```
date    treatment   sensor  temp
1/01/2019   1   A   30
2/01/2019   1   A   29.1
3/01/2019   1   A   21.2
4/01/2019   1   A   23.5
1/01/2019   1   B   20.5
2/01/2019   1   B   19.8
3/01/2019   1   B   35.1
4/01/2019   1   B   23.5
1/01/2019   2   C   31.2
2/01/2019   2   C   32.1
3/01/2019   2   C   28.1
4/01/2019   2   C   31.2
1/01/2019   2   D   31.2
2/01/2019   2   D   26.5
3/01/2019   2   D   27.9
4/01/2019   2   D   28
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34517370/group-by-into-fill-not-working-as-expected

Comment: Did you mean to provide some values in the temp column? Are you trying to carry a value forward or backward in time or merely carry a value across from another column?

Comment: `tidyr::fill()` is quite difficult to use in this example because when the data is grouped by date and treatment, one of the fills is "down" and the other "up".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
df <- df %>%
group_by(date, treatment) %>%
mutate(
  fill = mean(temp, na.rm=TRUE), # value to fill in blanks
  temp2 = case_when(!is.na(temp) ~ temp,
                    TRUE ~ fill)
  )
```

Comment: This worked nicely for what I was trying to achieve. Many thanks

Comment: You could also use `if_else` in this case, which is more compact, but I tend to use `case_when` most of the time because it's more flexible.

Comment: I also prefer using case_when

Answer (score 1):

Another option with `na.aggregate` from `zoo`

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
df %>% 
   group_by(date, treatment) %>%
   mutate(temp = na.aggregate(temp))
# A tibble: 16 x 4
# Groups:   date, treatment [8]
#   date      treatment sensor  temp
#   <fct>         <int> <fct>  <dbl>
# 1 1/01/2019         1 A       30  
# 2 2/01/2019         1 A       29.1
# 3 3/01/2019         1 A       21.2
# 4 4/01/2019         1 A       23.5
# 5 1/01/2019         1 B       20.5
# 6 2/01/2019         1 B       19.8
# 7 3/01/2019         1 B       35.1
# 8 4/01/2019         1 B       23.5
# 9 1/01/2019         2 C       31.2
#10 2/01/2019         2 C       32.1
#11 3/01/2019         2 C       28.1
#12 4/01/2019         2 C       31.2
#13 1/01/2019         2 D       31.2
#14 2/01/2019         2 D       26.5
#15 3/01/2019         2 D       27.9
#16 4/01/2019         2 D       28
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("1/01/2019", 
"2/01/2019", "3/01/2019", "4/01/2019"), class = "factor"), treatment = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
    sensor = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"
    ), class = "factor"), temp = c(30, 29.1, 21.2, NA, 20.5, 
    19.8, 35.1, 23.5, 31.2, 32.1, 28.1, 31.2, NA, 26.5, 27.9, 
    28)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option using `map2_dbl` from `purrr`. We `group_by` `treatment` and replace `NA` temp with the first non-NA `temp` with the same `date` in the group.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  group_by(treatment) %>%
  mutate(temp = map2_dbl(temp, date, ~if (is.na(.x)) 
                    temp[which.max(date == .y & !is.na(temp))] else .x))

#   date      treatment sensor  temp
#   <fct>         <int> <fct>  <dbl>
# 1 1/01/2019         1 A       30  
# 2 2/01/2019         1 A       29.1
# 3 3/01/2019         1 A       21.2
# 4 4/01/2019         1 A       23.5
# 5 1/01/2019         1 B       20.5
# 6 2/01/2019         1 B       19.8
# 7 3/01/2019         1 B       35.1
# 8 4/01/2019         1 B       23.5
# 9 1/01/2019         2 C       31.2
#10 2/01/2019         2 C       32.1
#11 3/01/2019         2 C       28.1
#12 4/01/2019         2 C       31.2
#13 1/01/2019         2 D       31.2
#14 2/01/2019         2 D       26.5
#15 3/01/2019         2 D       27.9
#16 4/01/2019         2 D       28
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("1/01/2019", 
"2/01/2019", "3/01/2019", "4/01/2019"), class = "factor"), treatment = 
c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
sensor = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"
), class = "factor"), temp = c(30, 29.1, 21.2, NA, 20.5, 
19.8, 35.1, 23.5, 31.2, 32.1, 28.1, 31.2, NA, 26.5, 27.9, 
28)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```