# Insert rows with NAs conditional on rolling sum

Tags: r, dplyr

I am conducting an analysis where I am calculating a rate based partly on a rolling sum of days. I am performing this calculation using dplyr and group_by/summary/mutate operations.

However, the increments of the rolling sum of days differs by group. Ideally, I have a measurement every 30 days for a year. However, sometimes the measurements come 60 or 90 days apart.

For example:

```
df <- data.frame( ID = "Subject A",
                 cumulative_days = c(30, 60, 90, 180, 270, 360),
                 rolling_percent = c(.8, .6, .6, .4, .3, .2))
```

I want to turn this group in something like:

```
result <- data.frame(ID = "Subject A",
                     month = seq(1,12),
                 rolling_percent = c(.8, .6, .6, NA, NA, .4, NA, NA, .3, NA, NA, .2))
```

If I am able to reach the 'result' dataframe above, my plan is to leverage the dplyr/zoo solution described here: [fill in NA based on the last non-NA value for each group in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207162/fill-in-na-based-on-the-last-non-na-value-for-each-group-in-r)

Where I can fill in the NAs with the last non-NA observation.

In other words, I want to be able to turn N observations which cumulatively add up to a rolling sum of 360 into 12 observations. At that point, I believe I can apply the other linked solution to solve my problem.

I'm struggling to clearly describe this situation, so any advice on clarifying my problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(df) # or setDT to convert in place

dt[, .(ID, month = cumulative_days/30, rolling_percent)][
   CJ(ID = unique(ID), month = 1:12), on = c('ID', 'month')]
#           ID month rolling_percent
# 1: Subject A     1             0.8
# 2: Subject A     2             0.6
# 3: Subject A     3             0.6
# 4: Subject A     4              NA
# 5: Subject A     5              NA
# 6: Subject A     6             0.4
# 7: Subject A     7              NA
# 8: Subject A     8              NA
# 9: Subject A     9             0.3
#10: Subject A    10              NA
#11: Subject A    11              NA
#12: Subject A    12             0.2

# or simply make it a rolling join to achieve your desired final result
dt[, .(ID, month = cumulative_days/30, rolling_percent)][
   CJ(ID = unique(ID), month = 1:12), on = c('ID', 'month'), roll = T]
#           ID month rolling_percent
# 1: Subject A     1             0.8
# 2: Subject A     2             0.6
# 3: Subject A     3             0.6
# 4: Subject A     4             0.6
# 5: Subject A     5             0.6
# 6: Subject A     6             0.4
# 7: Subject A     7             0.4
# 8: Subject A     8             0.4
# 9: Subject A     9             0.3
#10: Subject A    10             0.3
#11: Subject A    11             0.3
#12: Subject A    12             0.2
```

Alternatively to the above selection of columns, you can just add a new `month` column:

```
dt[, month := cumulative_days/30][
   CJ(ID = unique(ID), month = 1:12), on = c('ID', 'month'), roll = T]
#           ID cumulative_days rolling_percent month
# 1: Subject A              30             0.8     1
# 2: Subject A              60             0.6     2
# 3: Subject A              90             0.6     3
# 4: Subject A              90             0.6     4
# 5: Subject A              90             0.6     5
# 6: Subject A             180             0.4     6
# 7: Subject A             180             0.4     7
# 8: Subject A             180             0.4     8
# 9: Subject A             270             0.3     9
#10: Subject A             270             0.3    10
#11: Subject A             270             0.3    11
#12: Subject A             360             0.2    12
```

Comment: Wow. Really stunning how fast this is compared to @adiana 's - much appreciated - solution, at least at the scale of the actual dataset I'm using. Applying that other function over a list of DFs was taking on the order of 10 minutes. This solution was instantaneous. Gotta find more ways to use data.table in future.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution joining your data.frame with a complete one

```
library(dplyr)
df$month<-df$cumulative_days/30
result<-data.frame(ID = "Subject A",month=seq(1,max(df$month))) %>% left_join(df) %>%
select(-cumulative_days)
```

If you want to apply your solution to different IDs, like in this fake dataset:

```
df <- data.frame( ID = "Subject A",
              cumulative_days = c(30, 60, 90, 180, 270, 360),
              rolling_percent = c(.8, .6, .6, .4, .3, .2))

df2 <- data.frame( ID = "Subject B",
              cumulative_days = c(30, 90, 120, 180, 270, 360),
              rolling_percent = c(.6, .4, .3, .2, .1, .6))

df<-rbind(df,df2)
```

you can declare the previous code as a function, then splitting the big dataframe based on the IDs and apply the function singularly, binding all together at the end. So the code would be like:

```
buildDf<-function(df){
 df$month<-df$cumulative_days/30
 data.frame(ID = df$ID[1],month=seq(1,max(df$month))) %>% 
 left_join(df) %>% select(-cumulative_days)
}

listDf<-split(df,f=df$ID)
listDfFiltered<-lapply(listDf,buildDf)
result<-do.call('rbind',listDfFiltered)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! This does exactly what I would need for the example I provided. Can you suggest a way to extend this for multiple subjects, i.e. where df may contain "Subject A", "Subject B", etc etc.

Comment: `dfA <- data.frame( ID = "Subject A",
                  cumulative_days = c(30, 60, 90, 180, 270, 360),
                  rolling_percent = c(.8, .6, .6, .4, .3, .2));

dfB <- data.frame( ID = "Subject B",
                  cumulative_days = c(30, 90, 180, 360),
                  rolling_percent = c(.5, .6, .6, .4));

df_all <- rbind(dfA, dfB)`

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `base R`.  Create the 'month' column by dividing by 30.  Then, use `expand.grid` to get a data.frame with all the combinations of 'ID' and the `range` of 'month`,`merge` with the original dataset so that we get NA for 'rolling_percent' for 'ID', 'month' combination that is not found in the 'df'.

```
df$month <-df$cumulative_days/30
merge(expand.grid(ID = unique(df$ID), 
       month=Reduce(`:`, range(df$month))), df[-2], all.x=TRUE)
#          ID month rolling_percent
#1  Subject A     1             0.8
#2  Subject A     2             0.6
#3  Subject A     3             0.6
#4  Subject A     4              NA
#5  Subject A     5              NA
#6  Subject A     6             0.4
#7  Subject A     7              NA
#8  Subject A     8              NA
#9  Subject A     9             0.3
#10 Subject A    10              NA
#11 Subject A    11              NA
#12 Subject A    12             0.2
```