# Impute character values in column

Tags: r, imputation

My code looks like this:

```
Item | Category
A    |    1
A    |
A    |
A    |    1
A    |
A    |
A    |    1
B    |    2
B    |
B    |
B    |    2
B    |
B    |
B    |    2
B    |
B    |
```

I want to impute values and fill the "Category" column with the values corresponding to each "Item", wherever it isn't blank. The end result should be like this:

```
Item | Category
A    |    1
A    |    1
A    |    1
A    |    1
A    |    1
A    |    1
A    |    1
B    |    2
B    |    2
B    |    2
B    |    2
B    |    2
B    |    2
B    |    2
B    |    2
B    |    2
```

How can I do this in R?

Comment: Do you have a one to one mapping of item and category? What is your imputation approach?

Comment: Would `Category` have same value for every group ? You can replace blanks with `NA` and then use `na.locf`. Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207162/fill-in-na-based-on-the-last-non-na-value-for-each-group-in-r)

Comment: looks like `zoo::na.locf()`

Comment: are your Categories always the same? (i.e. all 1 for Item A, all 2 for Item B)? If so then something like `df$Category <- with(df, ave(Category, Item, FUN = function(i) i = i[i != ''][1]))`

Comment: @RonakShah - thank you! That was exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Sotos - thank you! Your solution worked too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `fill` from `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
    fill(Category)
```

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work. Assuming that the blank fields were actually NAs, how would you go about it?

Comment: @Great_Raisin  Taht is a great question.  Updated the post